# Associating two columns in the same Model class to the same column in another Model - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Quick question - I have two model classes - **Transactions** and **Accounts**.

The **Account** Model looks as follows:

```
 create_table "accounts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "account_name"
    t.integer  "account_number"
    t.boolean  "current_asset"
    t.boolean  "non_current_asset"
    t.boolean  "current_liability"
    t.boolean  "non_current_liability"
    t.boolean  "equity"
    t.boolean  "cost_of_sales"
    t.boolean  "operating_expense"
    t.boolean  "sales"
    t.boolean  "other_income"
    t.boolean  "bank"
    t.datetime "created_at",            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",            null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

The **Transaction** Model looks as follows:

```
 create_table "transactions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "date"
    t.string   "description"
    t.string   "reference"
    t.integer  "amount"
    t.integer  "account_id"
    t.boolean  "payment"
    t.boolean  "receipt"
    t.integer  "bank_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",          null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.boolean  "vat"
    t.integer  "vat_amount"
    t.integer  "transaction_form_id"
    t.integer  "contact_id"
  end
```

A user adds a new transaction which, through collection_select 
they to choose an Account which displays all the accounts except for where bank == true (where `bank == true` it represents a bank account).

When a user selects a Bank, they can only choose a bank account - where `bank==true` (again through collection select).

I need to run a method that allows me to call all the Transaction amounts through the Account model based on the bank_id and not the account_id. So how would i associate two different columns of my Transaction model to the same column in the Accounts class through either account_id or bank_id.

The method will look something like:

```
<% Account.each do |account| %>
<% if account.bank == true && account.transaction(:bank_id) == account.id %>
<%= account.number %>
<%= account.number %>
<%= account.transactions.sum(:amount) %>
<% end %>
```

Ps: I know this is in my views, not controller, but that's for another discussion!

[An image of Models example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgjHu.png)

Comment: Can you post the code for both models where you describe the relations between them? (`belongs_to/has_many`)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you back up and re-think your approach.

A bank account and a GL account are very different things (even though they both use the word 'account'). Using a single model to represent both of these will lead to confusion and a lot of empty fields. Consider using a `BankAccount` and a `GLAccount` (you can use custom `inflection` on `GLAccount`, if you like, so you can do `gl_account`).

If you use `BankAccount` and `GLAccount`, then you can simply do a polymorphic association on your `Transaction` model, something like:

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account, polymorphic: true
end
```

You would need to change your  `transactions` table to include `account_type` and `account_id` for that to work.

Then, your `BankAccount` and `GLAccount` models would look something like:

```
class BankAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions, as: :account
end
```

and

```
class GLAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions, as: :account
end
```

In which case, to iterate the BankAccounts, you would do something like:

```
<% BankAccount.all.each do |bank_account| %>
  <%= bank_account.number %>
  <%= bank_account.transactions.sum(:amount) %>
<% end %>
```

That'll end up with an N+1 query problem, but you can sort that out separately.

BTW, on your GL Accounts, you should use `enums` for the account type. As you currently have it set up, you will *always* have 8 empty boolean fields (not good). That might look something like:

```
class GLAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transactions, as: :account

  enum account_type: {
    current_asset:          0,
    non_current_asset:      1,
    current_liability:      2,
    non_current_liability:  3,
    equity:                 4,
    cost_of_sales:          5,
    operating_expense:      6,
    sales:                  7,
    other_income:           8
  }

end
```

Your `gl_accounts` table would need to include `account_type` as an integer for that to work.

A couple of other random notes:

- `if account.bank == true` should just be `if account.bank`
- You repeat `<%= account.number %>`

Given, however, what you have done, you could do something like:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many bank_transactions, class_name: 'Transaction', foreign_key: :bank_id
end
```

In which case, you should be able to do:

```
<% Account.where(bank: true).each do |bank_account| %>
  <%= bank_account.number %>
  <%= bank_account.bank_transactions.sum(:amount) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I can’t tell you how much I’ve just learnt from this answer! I’m pretty new to all this and greatly appreciate answers like this!

Comment: Great! Feel free to upvote/accept for future searchers.

Comment: by the looks of things - you know your way around an accounting system and its structure - any recommendations on any resources relating to this? Apologies if this is off the scope of the question and the forum.

Comment: Yes, I have a lot of experience working with accounting systems - using, configuring, and integrating with. What sort of resources do you have in mind?

Comment: Any reading material on accounting/enterprise systems with rails? I come from an accounting background - but the software side of things are obviously a bit more tricky!

Comment: Hm. Nothing specific to rails. BTW, an upvote/accept would be nice.